# Destroying Session - Logs me out to current system and the other system

Tags: php

Good day everyone, i just have a question,

In localhost i have several systems, when i open 2 or more systems, I login the first one, then the other doesn't have sessions yet.

But when I log out one of them, All sessions are being destroyed. Is it normal?
or is it a kind of vulnerability?

When you destroy a session in the same server like localhost, it will destroy other sessions in it?

```
http://localhost/system1    Active Session  $_SESSION['admin']
http://localhost/system2    Active Session  $_SESSION['admin']
```

I logout http://localhost/system1  with session_destroy() then it results to

```
http://localhost/system1    Inactive Session  
http://localhost/system2    Inactive Session
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: [`session_destroy`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) destroys all data registered to a session, so even sessions from your other system will be destroyed as well

Comment: `unset()` may help to release your selected session key=>value

Comment: @Swellar and Soni Vimal, Thanks for the information! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions are destroyed on the host,

If you are using Apache you could use virtualhosts to create local domains. Then access each site on either example.local or example2.local

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example1"
    ServerName www.example.local

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example2"
    ServerName www.example2.local

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

More on that here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html

Or you could try using PHPs builtin web server by running `php -S localhost:8000` in the web root of one folder and `php -S localhost:8001` in the other. Then you'd access them on http://localhost:8000 and http://localhost:8001. haven't tested this one though.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Another option would be to use named sessions http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php

Answer (score 2):

If for both systems you are using the same session id (in other words it means the same session file/entity), then yes it is normal. Because you actually have only one session which contains data from a few systems.

Your systems can use different sessions, but for that you need manually genereate the session ID (take a look into http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-create-id.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php for how to change the cookie path).

In your situation the eassest solution would be to unset the system data from a session (on logout), then the other system data will be not removed.

Answer (score 1):

sessions are set for hosts and not subfolders.
When you create a session , it is created on **localhost**,
Now that session variable can accessed by both of your system1 and system2,

using **session_destroy();** destroys the session from your host. so it deletes all session references.

I think you would want to particularly unset a variable of a particular site. so use this.

```
unset($_SESSION['system1session']);
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use different names for each Session.

PHP has a Session Name Function, which specifies the Name for the Cookie and therefore two different Names will have there own scope and ID.

One File:

```
session_name("ServerApp1"):;
session_start();

$_SESSION["a"] = ...
```

Other File:

```
session_name("ServerApp2"):;
session_start();

$_SESSION["a"] = ...
```

Using this approach you can distroy the Session in one file while the other one will be untouched.